# Trouble using the auth0 react lock example with redux and react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, auth0

Working off the auth0 lock react auth redux example here: https://github.com/auth0-blog/redux-auth/tree/auth0-lock

And using it for react native, I'm trying to call an auth0 login screen as part of my action dispatch in a redux react native app and I'm getting the error `"Cannot have a non-function arg after a function arg"`  What does that error mean and why does it happen when I'm trying to call an auth0 lock function from within an action dispatch?

```
// actions.js

function showLogin() {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
  };
}

function loginSuccess(profile, token) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    profile,
    token,
  };
}

function loginError(err) {
  return {
    type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
    err,
  };
}

export function login() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(showLogin());
    // it seems to error on the next line here calling the auth0 login method
    lock.show((err, profile, token) => {
      if (err) {
        // handle error
        return dispatch(loginError(err));
      }
      return dispatch(loginSuccess(profile, token));
    });

  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question tags I'm assuming that the `lock` variable refers to the Auth0 Lock made available in [`react-native-lock`](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock).

If that's the case, the [API docs](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock#lock) indicate that **the `show` method declares two parameters `options` and `callback`, but you're only passing a single argument when you call it**.

Comment: Yes, that's it!  I was using code from the auth0 react sample code which has a slightly different lock function vs the auth0 react native lock version.  I've updated the question title to more accurately reflect the issue and the the answer.